# How update auto processing to pending after success online payment in magento?

Tags: php, mysql, magento-1.9

How auto update processing to pending after success online payment in sales order grid magento1.9.3 ?
please help me

Comment: have you tried reading the magento docs ?

Comment: no i have not idea but how to update this query  UPDATE mg_sales_flat_order_grid SET status='pending' WHERE increment_id='$orderid'

Answer (score 1):

add code in success.phtml

```
$current_url=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$c_url_array=explode("//",$current_url);
$host_url="//".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$required_url=$c_url_array[0].$host_url;

$orderObj = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
$lastOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId());
$orderid=$this->getOrderId
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId());
$quoteId = $order['quote_id'];
$url_full1=$required_url.'/update-sales-order.php?quote_id='.$quoteId.'&orderid='.$orderid;
$b=file_get_contents($url_full1);
echo $b;
```

create file in main update-sales-order.php

```
$database="your datebase name";
    $hostname='localhost';
    $username='your database user name';
    $password='your database password';
    $connection = mysql_connect($hostname,$username, $password) OR DIE ('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.');
    mysql_select_db($database,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
    $quoteId=$_GET['quote_id'];
    $orderid=$_GET['orderid'];
    //$customer_id=$_GET['customer_id'];    
    $ip_address=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; 
    $update_sales_order="UPDATE mg_sales_flat_order_grid SET status='pending' WHERE increment_id='$orderid'";
    mysql_query($update_sales_order);
```